# How can we define implicit differentiation in terms of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

For a function we define derivative as

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{f(x+h)-f(x)}}{h}$$

But how can we write something like that for implicit function like for example $y=e^{x+y}$ or a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$.
Can we even define limit for such a function?

Comment: No new definition needed. Implicit differentiation is the name of a technique.

Comment: To expand on NDB, an implicit function is still a function. It is a technique for defining a function, but once the function is defined, the definition of the derivative can be applied to it as normal. There is nothing different between a properly-defined implicit function and a function defined in some other way  (just writing out some equation is not sufficient to define an implicit function). Implicit differentiation is a technique for differentiating implicit functions, assuming that they are differentiable.

Comment: how is circle a function @PaulSinclair

Comment: $y(x) = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ and $y(x) = -\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$, both defined for $x \in [-r, r]$ are the two continuous functions $y(x)$ definable implicitly from $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, with maximal domains. If you drop the continuous requirement, then there are uncountably many such functions, depending on which sign of $y$ you choose for each value of $x$.

Comment: thanks for helping me